# Listbox not populated VB 2015

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have this code:

```
FileOpen(1, "c:\FP_Software\Design_2016\designados.txt", OpenMode.Input)

While Not EOF(1)

    Input(1, nome)
    Input(1, leitorwt)
    Input(1, indicador)
    Input(1, c_som)
    Input(1, p_micros)

    nomeirmao = nome


    'Vai ler os registos que há em ficheiro e apresentá-los na grelha
    FileOpen(2, "c:\FP_Software\Design_2016\designacoes.txt", OpenMode.Input)

    While Not EOF(2)

        Input(2, dia)
        Input(2, nome1)
        Input(2, nome2)
        Input(2, nome3)
        Input(2, nome4)
        Input(2, nome5)
        Input(2, nome6)
        Input(2, nome7)
        Input(2, nome8)

        If nomeirmao = nome1 Then
            a1 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome2 Then
            a2 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome3 Then
            a3 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome4 Then
            a4 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome5 Then
            a5 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome6 Then
            a6 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome7 Then
            a7 = dia
        End If
        If nomeirmao = nome8 Then
            a8 = dia
        End If

        dtx.Rows.Add(nomeirmao, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8)

        ListBox1.Items.Add(dia)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dtx

        DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)


    End While


    FileClose(2)

End While

FileClose(1)
```

The code populates correctly the DGV but it's not populating the listbox; however, I'm using a variable which is the same to populate the DGV.
Anyone out there can give me a clue or explain why this happens?
It would be very appreciated

Comment: Did you set the DataSource of the ListBox after or before this code?

Comment: It is the variable dia which comes from the textfile opened before.